# C++ Lite Question 10.19. Function instead of variable decl

Tags: c++, constructor

I had this problem happen to me in the past http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.19

My question is, when writing

```
Foo x(Bar());
```

Why is it "declaring a non-member function that returns a Bar object" ? i can understand it if i wrote

```
Foo x(Bar);
```

But what does it think the () means in Bar()?

Answer (score 5):

`Bar()` there means "a function that takes no arguments and returns `Bar`". Consider a declaration of such a function:

```
Bar GetBar();
```

if you remove the name of the function from this, what remains will describe the function type. Some examples of where it's used is in template arguments; e.g. you can write this:

```
std::function<int(float)> f1;
std::function<Bar()> f2;
```

Hopefully this explains the syntax in general. Now what this means in this particular case. When a function type is used as a type of function argument, it is automatically subsituted for a function pointer type. So the equivalent (but clearer) declaration would be:

```
Foo x(Bar(*)());
```

Comment: ah i understand. i always thought you MUST write Bar(*)()

Comment: "for a type of variable": Can you please clarify what you mean with that? This equivalence is only true for a function parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following more simple example:

```
void fn1(int a)
{
}
```

fn1 is a function that takes a single int paramter.

Now take a look at fn2:

```
//Same as typing void fn2(int (*b)()) 
void fn2(int b())
{
}
```

Here fn2 does not take in an int, but it takes in a function that returns an int.

Now if you wanted to declare fn1 you could type it like so:

```
void fn1(int);//ommit the parameter name
```

And you can also declare fn2 like so:

```
void fn2(int());
```

Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>

int a()
{
  sd::cout<<"hi"<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}

void fn2(int b())
{
  b();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  fn1(3);
  fn2(a);
}
```

Output will be:

> hi

Now there is one more topic to understand... You can forward declare functions with scope.

a.cpp:

```
void a()
{
  void c();
  c();
}

//void b()
//{
//   c();//<--- undeclared identifier
//}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   a();
   return 0;
}
```

c.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

void c()
{
   std::cout<<"called me"<<std::endl;
}
```

> g++ a.cpp c.cpp
>   ./a.out

Output will be:

> Called me

And tying it all together.  If you do this:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  int b();

  return 0;
}
```

You are forward declaring a function called b() that returns type int and takes no parameters

If you would have done b = 3; then you'd get a compiling error as you can't assign a value to a forward declared function.

And once you've read all that it becomes clear:

```
Foo x(Bar());
```

You are forward declaring a function x that returns a type Foo and takes in a parameter to a function that returns a type Bar.

Comment: From what i understood i must always write void fn2(int (*b)())

Comment: It is the same as typing fn2(int (*b)())

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be online, but Scott Meyers' book, [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629), has a good, detailed explanation of what's going on in your example in **Item 6: Be alert for C++'s most vexing parse**.

On the plus side, the book is worth the price for anyone serious about C++.